# Time Machine not working. It has enough space but it keeps telling there is not enough space

Tags: time-machine, big-sur

Time Machine keeps showing me this message in Big Sur. The disk needs 46GB and only 97GB are available so it cannot create a backup. I was expecting the update to Monterey might help but seems I'm running a late 2014 model MacBook Pro and Monterey is available from early 2015 and on.

Anyone has been able to fix this. I've been using this backup disk for over 3 years without any issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you add to your question, disk Time Machine plugged,  the result (in text mode) from the terminal command `diskutil list` ?